# alert dialog code error in android studio

Tags: android

i was trying to make alert dialog box in android studio and it gives me a wierd error

> AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog().Builder(this);

on `AlertDialog()` method  [image: the error]
and i do not know the reason

the java code

```
package com.example.amr.alertdialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static  Button btn_alert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        onButtonClickListener();
    }
    public void onButtonClickListener()
    {
        btn_alert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn_alert.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                      AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog().Builder(this);
                        a_builder.setMessage("you click alert").setCancelable(false).
                              setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                              {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                  {
                                      finish();

                                  }
                              })
                              .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                              {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                  {
                                      dialog.cancel();

                                  }
                              });
                        AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
                        alert.setTitle("LALALALALALALA");
                        alert.show();


                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Builder is a subclass of AlertDialog, not a member variable.

You need to use

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

TheWanderer answer is correct! All you really need to do is change:

```
AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog().Builder(this);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

However, you might want to consider extracting the code that creates and shows your `AlertDialog` and put it into a separate method. That way you can reuse the code and your code will be easier to read and debug.

```
public void onButtonClickListener()
{
    btn_alert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_alert.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    showAlertDialog("LALALALALALALA", "you click alert")
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Now add the code for creating and showing the `AlertDialog`:

```
private void showAlertDialog(String title, String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton(
            "Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton(
            "No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: when i tried that it gave me  AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context:this);

Comment: Did you not try to just copy/paste my `showAlertDialog()` method?

Comment: No i did not try to copy your method i just modify the line of alert dialog definition as you said

Comment: So, is there any issue? I do not understand your comment "when i tried that it gave me..."

Comment: i mean when modified the line AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog().Builder(this); to AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); as you said it gives me error also

Comment: How about just trying the code `showAlertDialog()` and see if that helps.

Comment: @AmrHassan :: trust me the better way to do this is to use the `showAlertDialog()` method. It makes your code cleaner, more reusable and easier to debug.

Comment: @AmrHassan :: But, if you only want to get your code to work then you should understand, that you have put the constructor of the `AlertDialog.Builder` inside an anonymous class (please learn what an anonymous class is). By doing so using `this` inside the anonymous class will point to that class and not the `Activity` class. So, to get this to work inside the anonymous class do this  `AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);` . That way `this` is now pointing to `MainActivity`